# how to make wordpress user submit form once?

Tags: php

i'm working in client zone, and i want to make wordpress user can submit form once, and show html code if he submitted before.
can you guys help me to do that?

i tried to do this, but it dosen't work.

```php
global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user() ;
$client_usercurrent = $current_user->user_login;
$myArr = array();

if (in_array($client_usercurrent, $myArr)) {
    echo "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYes";
}

$myArr() = $client_usercurrent;

/* end submit  */
/* if current user exsits in $myarr we should hide the form */

if (in_array($client_usercurrent, $myArr)) {
    echo "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYes";
}
```

thanks

Comment: Are these all logged in users? How are you saving the form data in the database? You could either check if the user has a submitted form there by running a SQL query against the submitted data, or you could save a value against the user when the form is submitted (e.g. a pointer or ID to the form) in user meta.

Comment: I feel like there's a lot of your code missing.  Can you update your question?  Also, what Rup's saying is probably your best bet really; just record that the user has completed the form already and run a conditional check against the user meta to see if the form has been completed.  If there's more than one form you could add an array of completed form IDs and check against multiples, that'd make your solution extensible and scalable.